# System.Reflection.Emit to Implement a WebChannelFactory for Silverlight 4?

Tags: wcf, rest, reflection, silverlight-4.0, reflection.emit

This question follows upon someone else's question because the asker never accepted or said the solution to his problem, if he found one.

[What's the most portable way to make a Silverlight & Regular .NET REST client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/277623/266457)

If you're familiar with WebChannelFactory from .NET, it provides a clean way to create a client to access [WCF Web Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412204) (REST) services. There is no such class in Silverlight 4, so it might be worth creating a class that acts like it.

How would you get started in creating such as class, that creates a client that implements your service's contract ([TChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx))? I don't know how Microsoft did this, but it looks like they somehow create a new Type at runtime to implement the interface. Would you approach doing this in Silverilght? Maybe by looking at System.Reflection.Emit and [TypeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.addinterfaceimplementation.aspx)?

A more specific-to-System.Reflection.Emit question I have is, what's the simplest way to use MethodBuilder to create a method for your TypeBuilder, if you want to use existing compiled code? It looks like you could use [MethodBuilder.CreateMethodBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.REFLECTION.EMIT.METHODBUILDER.CREATEMETHODBODY%29;k%28CREATEMETHODBODY%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), however, in Silverlight 4 this does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a nice article. I decided to create a class which simplifies calling REST WCF services and more closely meets my needs. Maybe others will find it useful.

[WebHttpClient](http://regular-language.blogspot.com/2011/06/wcf-webhttp-rest-client-for-silverlight.html)

Answer (score 2):

First of all `WebChannelFactory` is not a clean way to build REST client - that is completely RESTless approach because it requires you to share all contracts between service and client. `WebChannelFactory` exists to provide compatibility with standard WCF service clients and somehow (wrongly) simplify calling REST services written in .NET. That is also the answer how MS did it - there is no runtime creation of the type. Types are defined at design time.

Comment: Maybe "clean" was not the word. Pehaps "simplified"? Because it seems a lot simpler to invoke one of my OperationContract methods on the TChannel created by WebChannelFactory.CreateClient, than to have to deal with making the same request with WebClient and specifying the URL every time I make a request. I think I see why runtime creation of the TChannel is not necessary...I am working on creating an alternative to WebChannelFactory and WebClient in Silverlight...

Comment: Check this if it helps you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/04/29/consuming-rest-pox-services-in-silverlight-4.aspx